# When using chain in ConstraintLayout an blank space appears on top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using ConstraintLayout in fragment. 
When I create vertical chain with my views a blank spaces appear on top and bottom.
Without chain there is no blank spaces.

I am using:

com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0

androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta5

[image]

Here is my layout of fragment is:

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".login.screens.login.LoginFragment"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_ellipse_h284_w360"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_phone_number"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Welcome User!" />



        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/til_phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:hint="Phone number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/til_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_phone_number"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_password"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:text="Forgot password"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_password"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_pin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_forgot_password" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/iv_phone"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Use pin"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/iv_phone"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/iv_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/filter_black1"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_signup"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_pin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iv_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/phone_2"
            android:text="v1.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_signup" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Activity layout is:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".login.screens.login.LoginActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        />
</merge>
```

Why blank space appears? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not define `layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle` default is `Spread` if you want to remove top and bottom space you can define it to `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"` more detail you check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain)